# What storage space / daily storage is available in messages on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, online-storage

Gmail storage space is ~ 7000 MB for me. What can I expect for Facebook.

Can I send projects/videos across the platform without any holdup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is advertised as unlimited,

E.g. in [2007 Facebook Photo Storage](http://blog.facebook.com/blog.php?post=2406207130) was as follows

> Allow me to geek out and share some
>   photo infrastructure statistics with
>   you. We have:
>
> - 1.7 billion user photos
> - 2.2 billion friends tagged in user photos
> - 160 terabytes of photo storage used
>     with an extra 60 terabytes available
> - 60+ million photos added each week
>     which take up 5 terabytes of disk
>     space
> - 3+ billion photo images served to
>     users every day
> - 100,000+ images served per second
>     during our peak traffic windows

This month, the Facebook Engineering Team talked a bit about the messaging platform on their blog

> Since Messages accepts data from many
>   sources such as email and SMS, we
>   decided to write an application server
>   from scratch instead of using our
>   generic Web infrastructure to handle
>   all decision making for a user's
>   messages. It interfaces with a large
>   number of other services: we store
>   attachments in Haystack

And [Haystack](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=76191543919) is currently being used for Photos.

Though if you start racking up tens of gigabytes, it will get ugly.